# Ajax POST Javascript Objects to Zend Controller and recieving

Tags: php, javascript, json, zend-framework

I'm trying to pass javascript objects from view to update controller in Zend.

My JSON string looks like :

```
[{"item_id":null,"parent_id":"none","depth":0,"left":"1","right":4},{"item_id":"1","parent_id":null,"depth":1,"left":2,"right":3}]
```

and it's assigned to variable `jsonObj`.

My AJAX post looks like :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://dev.jp-websolutions.co.uk/cms_nishan/admin/navigation/update",
            data: jsonObj,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    ;
```

And my update controller is :

```
public function updateAction() {

        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        }

        $data = $this->_request->getPost();
        $result = Zend_Json::decode($data);
        print_r($result);
    }
```

But I cant get it to work, if I use

```
$result = Zend_Json::decode([{"item_id":null,"parent_id":"none","depth":0,"left":"1","right":4},{"item_id":"1","parent_id":null,"depth":1,"left":2,"right":3}]);
```

It displays properly, as

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[item_id] => 
[parent_id] => none 
[depth] => 0 
[left] => 1 
[right] => 4 ) 

[1] => Array ( [item_id] => 1 [parent_id] => [depth] => 1 [left] => 2 [right] => 3 ) )
```

How can I get this work? Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You're sending JSON as the request body, with no identifier, so on the PHP side you need to use `getRawBody()` to get the JSON:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getRawBody();
```

The `getPost()` method should only be used if the data was submitted with an identifier with contentType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Also make sure that your Javascript variable `jsonObj` is a string containing the JSON, not an object. If it's an object you will have to `jsonObj = JSON.stringify(jsonObj)`.

[Docs for Zend Request Object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html)

---

Alternatively you can send the JSON with an identifier. Change the ajax to:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://dev.jp-websolutions.co.uk/cms_nishan/admin/navigation/update",
            data: {json : jsonObj},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    };
```

On the PHP side, use `getPost('json')`:

```
$data = $this->_request->getPost('json');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now when I print_r, it says "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: jsonObj is a string containing JSON, sorry for the confusing variable name

Comment: Which version of ZF are you using? You need 1.5+ for `getRawBody()`. Also see my update for an alternate method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried that method too, but gives the non-object error,
in my controller I have -
$data = $this->_request->getPost('json');
        $result = Zend_Json::decode($data);
        $this->view->navigationObj -> print_r($result);

Comment: Try to narrow it down by just doing `var_dump($this->_request->getPost('json');); exit();` and see if that outputs the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use a object for the **Data** propery in the ajax,

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://dev.jp-websolutions.co.uk/cms_nishan/admin/navigation/update",
            data: {myData: jsonObj,somethingLese: 'else'},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    return false;
}
;
```

In the controller use  `$this->getRequest()->getParam('myData', null);` to access the data.

```
public function updateAction() {

        if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
            $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        }

        $data = $this->getRequest()->getParam('myData', null);
        $result = Zend_Json::decode($data);
        print_r($result);
    }
```

[Zend Request](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.request.html)

Comment: please clarify how to call this in zend controller, I'm confused

Comment: @NishanCK take a look at `$this->getRequest()->getParam('myData', null)` this is the usual method to get a paramether from the request